# How to check if a location lies within the "accuracy" of the polygon.- e.g. if the accuracy of the function is 30m

Tags: swift, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

This function is to check if latitude or longitude inside or outside the polygone.

```
 func isAvalibleinsidePolygone{
            let latitude = lat?.text
            let longitude = lon?.text
            if latitude != "" && longitude != "" {
                //            pathOfPolygon.removeAllCoordinates()
                for p in places {
                    pathOfPolygon.add(p.coordinate)
                }
    ifGMSGeometryContainsLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(latitude!)!, Double(longitude!)!), pathOfPolygon, true) {
                    alert(title:`enter code here` "YEAH!!!", msg: "You are inside the polygon")

                } else {
                 alert(title: "OPPS!!!", msg: "You are outside the polygon")
                }
            }
        }
```

But even i would like to check if a location lies within the "accuracy" of the polygon - e.g. if the accuracy of the function is 30m, any location that is within 30m of the polygon should still return true. So parameters will be like latitude,longitude,accuracy
 E.g:

```
func withinAccuracy(latitude:Double,longitude:Double,accuracy:Double){
//....
}
```

Comment: Its worked for me. Thank you

Comment: i´m glad to hear that. Posted the comment as answer so you could accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the function
 `GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance(_ point: CLLocationCoordinate2D, _ path: GMSPath, _ geodesic: Bool, _ tolerance: CLLocationDistance) -> Bool`  it does exactly what you want. [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils#gabc5e0113367e12d217afad9170257259)